# Поиск пустой строки по регулярке

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Объясните, пожалуйста, как найти пустую строку по регулярным выражениям? Пробовал сделать так:

```
var empty = /^\s[^a-zA-Z0-9_]|\s[^a-zA-Z0-9_]$/.test(obj.val()) === true ? true : false;
```

Но так, почему-то, вообще пропускаются все пробельные символы и переменная `empty` становится равна `false`. А нужно сделать так, чтобы если есть пробельные символы, но нет никаких других, то `empty = true`.

P.S. `false` значит не соответствует шаблону. `true` - наоборот.

Comment: `\s` используется для пробельных символов, `*` - для повторения предыдущей группы 0 или несколько раз. Непонятно, зачем Вы нагородили `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, когда обычный `/^\s*$/` должен сработать. Или есть еще какие-либо условия?

Comment: `=== true ? true : false` можно просто удалить, кстати.

Comment: `...  === true ? true : false` - по рукам за такое надо...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: На счет по рукам не понял)

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал так:

```
function isWhitespace(str) {
  return /^\s*$/.test(str);
}

var empty = isWhitespace(obj.val());
```

`^` значит начало строки, `\s` значит пробельный символ, `*` значит 0 раз или больше, и `$` значит конец строки.

Вот примеры:

```
isWhitespace("") // true
isWhitespace(" ") // true
isWhitespace(" \n\t \r  ") // true
isWhitespace(" a ") // false
```

Comment: Да, у меня, оказывается и до этого все работало, я просто не замечал. А как тогда отличить пробельный символ от пустого (если вообще ничего не написано)?

Comment: @rsandrey Если хотите проверить, пустая ли строка, то можно использовать `var isEmpty = str.length === 0;`.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо.